# JSON deserialization assumes local timezone if not provided for DateTimeOffset

Tags: vb.net, json.net, datetimeoffset

So I have been testing this all day with a simple setup. I am deserializing a JSON string into a class object. The only property is for a `DateTimeOffset` value. Just to test, I am not supplying a timezone with the JSON date property as I will not be able to control what a third party would send to me. Once it is deserialized, the property has assumed the timezone of my system. I get that this is probably intentional, but is it possible to make it assume UTC as I believe this would be a better option for my app?

What I want it to be: `01/01/1900 00:00:00 +00:00`

I have tried to use `JsonConverters`, but it seems to parse it as a `DateTimeOffset` before it gets to the `ReadJson` method and it does not give me access to the JSON string version of the property value so I can parse it properly.

Code and example below:

```
Public Class MyTest

    Public Property DTO As DateTimeOffset = #1900-01-01#

End Class

Public Sub TestMethod()

    Dim myDate As String = "{""DTO"": ""1900-01-01T00:00:00""}"

    Dim o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyTest)(myDate, 
        New JsonSerializerSettings With {
            .DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
            .DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
        })

 End Sub
```

As you can see, it has assumed my +2 timezone:

[image: Screenshot of myDate after deserialization]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to coax Json.Net to treat `DateTimeOffset` without an offset as UTC with the following settings:

```
Dim settings As New JsonSerializerSettings With {
    .DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
}
settings.Converters.Add(New IsoDateTimeConverter With {
    .DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal
})

Dim o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyTest)(myDate, settings)
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vgc9is

The key when using a `JsonConverter` to handle dates is to set `DateParseHandling` to `None`.  Otherwise otherwise the internal reader will try to handle it first.